# New Mikraot Gedolot - Chorev Publishers

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, product-recommendation, tanach

I am looking for reviews on the somewhat new [Mikraot Gedolot from Chorev Publishers](http://www.chorev.co.il/Product/36165575/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%A8-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94)

1. How is the quality of the print? Is it clear and easy to read for most people? There is a lot of information packed into five volumes that are only 7 x 10, so I'm wondering if the print is difficult to read as compared to lets say Torat Haim by Mossad HaRav Kook or Bar Ilan's Mikraot Gedolot.
2. How is the accuracy compared to other editions of Mikraot Gedolot? Has anyone noticed errors?
3. Does the section with thought provoking questions help the reader to understand the problems that the commentators are trying to work out? Or is supplemental material?
4. Which features does this set have that others do not offer?
5. Are there grammatical aids such as a bolded kamatz katan and sheva na?

Comment: All printed works have errors.

Comment: To whose wanting to close because "opinion-based", the OP is asking specific fact-based questions anyone with the book should easily be able to answer

Comment: #5 can be answered negatively by looking at the pictures on the site you posted.